# Suma con decimales

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de realizar una suma con decimales, estoy comenzando a usar `javascript` para hacer operaciones etc.

este es el script que utilizo:

```
<script>
  function sumar (valor) {
    var total = 0;  
    valor = parseInt(valor); // Convertir el valor a un entero (número).

    total = document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML;

    // Aquí valido si hay un valor previo, si no hay datos, le pongo un cero "0".
    total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;

    /* Esta es la suma. */
    total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));

    // Colocar el resultado de la suma en el control "span".
    document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
}
</script>
```

como puedo usar ese codigo para hacerlas con decimales y no solo con enteros??

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando tratas de hacer una suma con decimales? ¿Cuál es el separador de decimales que usas, punto, coma u otro?

Comment: al momento de tratar de hacer la suma con decimales no toma el numero que esta despues del punto. ej si pongo 1.2 solo toma el 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder obtener el `valor` en decimales debes utilizar `parseFloat` en lugar de `parseInt`, de lo contrario perderás las decimales y convertirás a entero. Por lo tanto, cambia `parseInt(valor)` por `parseFloat(valor)`.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` convierte los valores a enteros, en lugar de ese usa `parseFloat`.

A continuación un ejemplo con base en el código de la pregunta. Las líneas originales que habría que cambiar las he comentado y continuación el cambio propuesto.

```js
function sumar(valor) {
  var total = 0;
  //valor = parseInt(valor); // Convertir el valor a un entero (número).
  // total = document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML;

  total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML);

  // Aquí valido si hay un valor previo, si no hay datos, le pongo un cero "0".
  total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;

  /* Esta es la suma. */
  // total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));
  total += parseFloat(valor);

  // Colocar el resultado de la suma en el control "span".
  document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="number"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Sumar" onclick="let valor = document.querySelector('input[type=number]').value; sumar(valor);"/><br/>
<div id="spTotal">0</div>
```